# Is it possible to add prompt based on keywords passed to bash?

Tags: bash, centos

Say we are executing some CLI in bash (not to bash script). Example -

```
apt-get remove nginx
```

So is it possible to add a prompt to it like based on keywords ("apt-get remove", etc.)-

```
You are on a production machine. Are you sure you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Comment: sounds (to me) like you want something akin to zsh's `preexec`; a quick web search on `bash pre-command execution` brings up several hits like [this](https://superuser.com/q/175799) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259911)

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a little wrapper script which is located in a directory which is searched first.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $HOSNTAME = "XYZ" ]; then
  while :; do
    read -p "This is a production machine. Do you wish to continue [y/n]? " yn
    case "$yn" in [Yy]*) break ;; [Nn]*) exit;; *) echo "Please answer yes or no.";; esac
  done
fi
/usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
```

You can call this script `apt-get` which you place in `/path/to/wrapper/bin` and you update `PATH` in your profile to read `PATH=/path/to/wrapper/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I thought this initially, but this would hold true mainly for binaries but not for keywords. Say if we want the same thing to be prompted when a specific filename like - nginx.conf is mentioned (vim nginx.conf, vim /etc/nginx.conf, vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) then keyword-based match won't work via wrapper!